# Versioning of a network shared folder with a TFS repository

Tags: tfs, synchronization

I have a collection of scripts among with some executables on a network share folder.

From time to time I change these scripts, add new ones along with some new executables.

In order to be able to roll-back some inadvertent changes I would like to keep track of my changes.

The rest of my code sits in a Team Foundation Server repository and it would be best if I could just sync the network share with a folder in that repository.

I tried to use  `tf.exe` for this purpose, but as far as I understood I first need to create a workspace, map it to this folder etc -- that seems to be too complicated.

Is there any simple solution here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check-in the scripts to TFS, setup a simple build which copies the script files and replaces them on network share.

Answer (score 1):

Map your shared drive and create a TFS workspace to the mapped drive. Add all the files in the shared drive to TFS. 
Every time you are doing a change, checked out your file using

tf checkout "fileName"

do the changes and then check-in the file using 
tf checkin "filename"

Make sure to execute tf.exe on the mapped folder.